# Remove strong name key file from WPF app

Tags: c#, wpf

WPF desktop app in VS 2015, .NET framework 4

I recently purchased a certificate from a CA. In an existing app that was previously unsigned I can sign the manifest with my new certificate. My problem is when I check the "Sign the assembly" check box there is an existing .pfx file, that I had created, in the dropdown box.  Is there a way to get rid of that association, as if it's a new application?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the .pfx file from your project directory, it should dissapear from the dropdown list. If you want to remove the certificate from the store too, use this:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2167.how-to-use-the-certificates-console.aspx

or this:

http://www.thewindowsclub.com/certmgr-msc-certificate-manager-windows

Comment: The .pfx file was in the application's root. I removed it and re opened the project. The .pfx is still selected in the drop down and the project won't publish with an error "Could not find file......the pfx.